# trigger Jquery in dynamic combobox

Tags: jquery, .net, vb.net, combobox

I have a .net form which opens a webpage in webbrowser and selects 2 Combobox where the first Combobox value changes the value of the second Combobox values. like if i select "Assigned" in first Combobox , the second Combobox will have list of assigned reason, and similarly if i select "Pending" in first drop down, the second Combobox will have list of pending reason. Im able to select the value in first Combobox  however since this triggers a jquery(I guess) im unable get the second Combobox  value. i tried many answered questions in internet and noting seems to work. can someone help.

My HTML is

```
                          <table id="left_nav">
                           <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <label>Status</label>
                                <span id="editNavMenuLink" 
                         class="small_link">Click to edit</span>
                                <br/>
                                <div class="dynamic_select_holder">
                                  <select name="status" id="status">
                                      <option value=""

                                      ></option>
                                      <option value="Assigned"

                                      >Assigned</option>
                                      <option value="Researching"

                                      >Researching</option>
                                      <option value="Work In Progress"

                                      >Work In Progress</option>
                                      <option value="Pending"
                                           selected="selected"
                                      >Pending</option>
                                      <option value="Resolved"

                                      >Resolved</option>
                                  </select>
                                  <span>Pending</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="pending_reason_row" style="">
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <label id="pending_reason_label">Pending 
                                     Reason</label><br/>
                                <div class="dynamic_select_holder">
                                  <select name="pending_reason" 
                                   id="pending_reason">
                                    <option value=""/></option>
                                    <option value="Catalog Push" 
                           selected="selected"/>Catalog Push</option>
                                  </select>
                                  <span>Catalog Push</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

and while i inspect the element there is a EV symbol next to the select id = "status" and when i click on it it shows a a arrow symbol and next to it is change and then there is a symbol jquery and when i click on it it shows the following function:

```
         function() {
             if (this.value == "Pending") {
              $('#pending_reason_row').show();
                  } else {
              $('#pending_reason_row').hide();
                          }

             if (this.value == "Resolved" || this.value == "Closed") {
              $('#time_spent_row').show();
                } else {
             $('#time_spent_row').hide();
                 }


             if (this.value == "Resolved" || this.value == "Closed") {
                $('#closure_code_row').show();
              $('#root_cause_row').show();
                $('#root_cause_details_row').show();
                  $('#resolution_row').show();
              } else if (this.value == "Pending") {
                $('#root_cause_row').show();
                      $('#root_cause_details_row').show();
                         } else {
                    $('#closure_code_row').hide();
                        $('#root_cause_row').hide();
                     $('#root_cause_details_row').hide();
                      $('#resolution_row').hide();
                           }
                             }
```

i see that i somehow have to trigger this function so that the dynamic combobox will change. my vb code is this

```
  Me.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("status").SetAttribute("selectedIndex", 4)
```

Me.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pending_reason").SetAttribute("selectedIndex", 2)

so the first one will select in the first combobox and second line will select from second combobox and between these two lines i need the ways on how to trigger the jscript such that the second combobox will appear.

i tried for almost hours and nothing works. can someone help me the right way to do as is see im going somewhere wrong.

EDIT:
i ll try to give the information here instead of providing the total webpage since its my company internal website, please bear with me on this David. so this is a .net vb form project and i have a text box and button in my form lets say submit. so once i click the submit button, it should take the value from the text box and navigate to the webpage given in the text and once loaded, it should select the first combobox1 called status and set status from assigned to pending. once the status is set to pending, a new new combobox2 appears called pending reason will appear. and from there i need to select a pending reason. However when i navigate to the webpage though webbrowser1, once i set the first combobox to pending, the second combobox is not appearing. and the jquery is associated with the first combobox which triggers the second combobox. Please let me know if this is enough or feel free to ask more questions to help me on this issue.

Comment: Please use the snippet tool if possible to create a [mcve]

Comment: i ll try to give the information here instead of providing the total webpage since its my company internal website, please bear with me on this David.

Comment: Edited my question to add more information. please ask more info if needed. I know this may not be enough, however im a beginner in .net forms and im trying to learn and this is my first experience with jquery however this project was earlier working fine in a excel vba macro using selenium and chrome without the need to worry about jquery. now im unable to replicate the same using vb.net.

Comment: Still struggling. Any suggestions please